# Combining rows of datetime and their values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

Hello I would like to change the time interval of my datetime column and add the values that get grouped. Right now my datetimes are incrementing by 10 minutes with each datetime having a value, but I would like to have it increment by 30 minutes instead and add the values inside of those 30 minutes and have that sum be the value of the 30 minute datetime. Thanks!

ex:
current dataframe:

```
datetime              value  
1/1/2018 00:00:00     1  
1/1/2018 00:00:10     10  
1/1/2018 00:00:20     3  
1/1/2018 00:00:30     6
1/1/2018 00:00:40     2  
1/1/2018 00:00:50     4  
...
```

new dataframe:

```
datetime              value  
1/1/2018 00:00:00     14  
1/1/2018 00:30:00     12  
...
```

Comment: Those are not datetimes, they are timedeltas.  And your increments are 10 seconds not minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your `df` looks like

```
df

             datetime  value
0 2018-04-06 00:00:00      1
1 2018-04-06 00:10:00     10
2 2018-04-06 00:20:00      3
3 2018-04-06 00:30:00      6
4 2018-04-06 00:40:00      2
5 2018-04-06 00:50:00      4
```

---

Use `resample`

```
df.set_index('datetime').resample('30T').sum()

                     value
datetime                  
2018-04-06 00:00:00     14
2018-04-06 00:30:00     12
```

Comment: Fixed it! I already had datetime as my index so I just had to do resample with the sum.